# Differences in Missionaries Between Denominations

Tags: lds, jehovahs-witnesses, missionary

I've searched through most other missionary threads and have not found a decent answer to this. I am familiar with LDS/Jehovah's Witness' definitions of missionaries, usually as proselytizing missionaries going door to door attempting to convert people from one religion to theirs.

While I was perusing the other threads about missionaries, specifically the one here:
[Which churches today send the most missionaries?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/25252/which-churches-today-send-the-most-missionaries) I came across an interesting point that someone made. J Dawg's answer on the thread said something to the effect of "Mormon and Jehovah's Witness missionaries aren't really missionaries as they don't do *so and so*"

So my question is, why is there a discrepancy in what people think missionaries should be?

I feel like the bible outlines this pretty clearly in Matthew:
Matthew 28:19-20 (KJV)

> 19 Go ye therefore, and teach all nations, baptizing them in the name of the Father, and of the Son, and of the Holy Ghost:

> 20 Teaching them to observe all things whatsoever I have commanded you: and, lo, I am with you alway, even unto the end of the world. Amen.

As per Kris's comment, here is the definition of missionary I am looking at:

> A missionary is a member of a religious group that is sent into an area in order to promote its faith or provide services to people, such as education, literacy, social justice, health care, and economic development.

Under the definition of missionary provided, why do many denominations not consider LDS/JW "missionaries" to be missionaries?

Comment: Select a definition of the word missionary and add it to the question.  JWs for example do not refer to all preachers of the good news as missionaries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Differences in Missionaries Between Denominations?**

It is in the actual definition of the terms missionaries, proselytism  and evangelizing and the semantics of theses terms.

**What is a missionary?**

> A missionary is a member of a religious group that is sent into an area in order to promote its faith or provide services to people, such as education, literacy, social justice, health care, and economic development.
>
> In the Latin translation of the Bible, Jesus Christ says the word when he sends the disciples into areas and commands them to preach the gospel in his name. The term is most commonly used in reference to Christian missions, but it can also be used in reference to any creed or ideology.
>
> The word mission originated in 1598 when Jesuits, the members of the Society of Jesus sent members abroad, derived from the Latin missionem (nom. missio), meaning 'act of sending' or mittere, meaning 'to send'. - [Missionary](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missionary)

**What is proselytism?**

> Proselytism is the policy of attempting to convert people's religious or political beliefs. Carrying out attempts to instill beliefs can be called proselytization.
>
> Sally Sledge discusses religious proselytization as the marketing of religious messages. Proselytism is illegal in some countries. Some draw distinctions between evangelism and proselytism, regarding proselytism as involuntary or coerced; the two terms can also be understood to merely be synonyms. - [Proselytism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proselytism)

**What is evangelizing?**

> In Christianity, evangelism or witnessing is the act of preaching the gospel with the intention of sharing the message and teachings of Jesus Christ. It is sometimes associated with Christian missions.
>
> Christians who specialize in evangelism are often known as evangelists, whether they are in their home communities or living as missionaries in the field, although some Christian traditions refer to such people as missionaries in either case. Some Christian traditions consider evangelists to be in a leadership position; they may be found preaching to large meetings or in governance roles. In addition, Christian groups who encourage evangelism are sometimes known as evangelistic or evangelist. [Evangelism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evangelism)

Now with these terms somewhat defined, we can see why some Christians do not see proselytism as a valid form of missionary activity.

Proselytism has limits and this is recognized by the World Council of Churches.

> The World Council of Churches in The Challenge of Proselytism and the Calling to Common Witness states the following:
>
> 19. Proselytism as described in this document stands in opposition to all ecumenical effort. It includes certain activities which often aim at having people change their church affiliation and which we believe must be avoided, such as the following:
>
> - making unjust or uncharitable references to other churches' beliefs and practices and even ridiculing them;
> - comparing two Christian communities by emphasizing the achievements and ideals of one, and the weaknesses and practical problems of the other;
> - employing any kind of physical violence, moral compulsion and psychological pressure e.g. the use of certain advertising techniques in mass media that might bring undue pressure on readers/viewers;
> - using political, social and economic power as a means of winning new members for one's own church;
> - extending explicit or implicit offers of education, health care or material inducements or using financial resources with the intent of making converts;
> - manipulative attitudes and practices that exploit people's needs, weaknesses or lack of education especially in situations of distress, and fail to respect their freedom and human dignity.
>
> [Proselytism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proselytism)

On October 13,2016 Pope Francis said that  “Proselytism is the strongest venom against the path of ecumenism.”

In a homily given on Aug. 5, 2013, Pope Francis discussed the differences between evangelization and proselytization.

In short missionary activities must not be strictly preaching the Gospel in all charity and by example without crossing the line simply proselytizing other Christians to another denomination. This is what some see a not being a true missionary spirituality.

> For instance:
>
> - Evangelization goes out to others and listens to them; proselytization excludes others and simply talks at them.
> - Evangelization is a proclamation of Jesus, allowing people to have an encounter with Christ; proselytization is proud and convinced that it has all the answers.
> - Evangelization trusts in the Holy Spirit as the true evangelist, as the one who makes converts; proselytization believes it's up to us, to the force of our arguments and persuasive power.
>
> [Evangelization Vs. Proselytization.](https://www.thedivinemercy.org/articles/evangelization-vs-proselytization)

Some Christian denominations would not see door to door evangelizing as a form of missionary activity, but more as a form of proselytism, over a classical definition of missionary activity in the cultural and historical meaning of the term. As
I said earlier, a question of semantics is very much involved here.

Remember that Our Lord said, [***“Go forth into the whole world and proclaim the gospel to all creation.”***](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%2016%3A15%2CLuke%2014%3A23%2CMatthew%2028%3A19-20%2CActs%201%3A7-8%2CMark%2016%3A15-16&version=NCB) He never said go and argue the Gospel!

Comment: Thank you for the response! I appreciate the definitions. I originally thought there was some form of canonical bit I was missing (presumably in the Bible) but after having read your response and doing a little further digging of my own, I have come to the same conclusion that it is, in fact, a matter of semantics. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The question is limited to considering Jehovah's Witness missionary work and Latter Day Saint missionary work, with a view to discovering why there is a discrepancy in what people think missionaries should be, and why others do not view them as doing missionary work (as that relates to Matthew 28:19-20.)

The meaning of the word 'missionary' could turn out to be a red-herring, detracting from the point of the question. It should suffice to accept, without question, what those two groups consider to be the meaning. Whoever they wish to designate as their missionaries, fine. Let's just run with that. They could be full-time or part-time members; they could be working "in the field" for many years, or just a limited time (two years, one month, or some other time period.) They could be volunteers, paying their own way, or be given financial support from their headquarters. **The one critical factor the question makes clear is that they should be devoted to doing what Jesus commanded in Matthew 28:19-20.**

Each group considers their missionaries to be doing that - but not the other's.

The only religious groups that would deny both the JWs and the LDS are being true to Matthew 28:19-20 are those who maintain that they are not converting people to the faith of Jesus Christ, but to a particular faith system that has some critically important aspects at odds with mainstream, orthodox Christian belief.

So, what is the point of Jesus' commission to the first-century Church? It is to spread out, going global, teaching something particular, baptising with a particular 'formula' ***so as to identify individuals as followers of Jesus Christ.***

Getting answers to particular questions will show a clear differentiation between both those groups. What they teach are the doctrines and practices of their own denomination. Therefore, are they teaching as the gospel, as the message of salvation, the same thing? If so, then they would not mind if a convert was baptised by one group, or the other. Do they mind? Or are they not convinced that the other group is teaching the biblical gospel? Let them come out with a simple "Yes" or "No" and all will become clear. When they repeat the baptismal words, "In the name of the Father, and of the Son, and of the Holy Spirit" do they mean the same thing, or is one's idea of who the Father is, and who the Son is, and who the Holy Spirit is - different to the other's? Anybody who knows their respective doctrines on that knows what the answer is.

***This is about what they teach as the biblical gospel, and who the biblical Christ is.*** Neither group thinks the other's teaching is right, which is why their respective missionaries could never join ranks, or co-operate with teaching - unlike most mainstream, orthodox groups, whose missionaries will support other missionaries and combine efforts to help the cause of Christ. This is particularly seen in Bible Societies. But the JWs only publish and strive to distribute their own version of the Bible, and the LDS strive to publish and promote their Book of Mormon. Neither group will encourage interested people to mingle amongst other denominations, unlike in many Protestant groups.

So, this answer does not deny that both groups have their respective missionaries, who are very active. But what it does flag up is the need for people to first grasp just who the Jesus of the Bible is and what the gospel of salvation is. Biblical literacy is vital for people. Those two groups of missionaries claim to teach the Bible, but if people don't first know from their own study just what it says, they will be none the wiser as to why they should ask probing questions about what they are being told is biblical. Same with any denominational teaching, of course.

If you do know the biblical Christ and the gospel of Christ, you will know the discrepancies. If you don't know, you won't. Time people stopped being spoon-fed by cold-callers, or random web-sites perhaps, and did their own Bible homework?

Comment: Under the definition of missionary provided, why do many denominations not consider LDS/JW "missionaries" to be missionaries?   You don’t answer the actual question

Comment: @Kris  Noboby denies that they are missionaries. The Q is whether they meet the criteria for that which Jesus gave in Mat.28. Both groups claim they do. Simple logic shows up the problem. They preach/teach a different version of who Jesus is, and different scripture. Each denies the other missionaries are the genuine Mat.28 missionaries. Well, they certainly both can't be right. Many other denoms. say neither of them promulgate the biblical Jesus/scripture.

Comment: JWs do not call all evangelizes missionaries. Thst term is reserved for a specially trained group of JWs who are assigned to various locations around the world.  It doesn’t matter that you find the message uncomfortable since it does not conform to mainstream doctrine.   The question is not asking for explanations of why LDS and JW teachings are not accepted by mainstreamers but  Asks why the folks those two denominations send forth as missionaries are not viewed as missionaries.  There is no good reason to claim they are not missionaries if they fit the definition given by OP

Comment: @Kris, you misunderstand me. I agree entirely with whoever JWs call 'missionaries' that they are missionaries. I deal with why many non-JWs and non-JDSs say JW and LDS missionaries do not fulfil the requirements of Mat.28. Of course you are going to disagree with me. But I agree with the definition given by the OP, and my answer goes along with that. I will not argue with you.

Comment: “nobody denies that they are missionaries“.    The premise of the OP is that many do deny that LDS and jw missionaries are “real” missionaries.